# How to set shape parameters for Johnson SU distribution in python scipy?

Tags: distributions, python, skewness, parameterization, kurtosis

- The Johnson SU distribution has 4 parameters
  ($\delta,\gamma,\lambda,\xi$),
- but `scipy.stats.johnsonsu` only has 2 parameters ($a,b$).

Why the difference. how can I shape the Johnson SU density in python?

[scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.johnsonsu.html) says $a,b$ both take non-negative values, which all make the density negatively skewed when I plot them. I would like to customize for positive skewness

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All scipy distributions have a `scale` and `loc` parameter too. So, as scipy arguments:

$$\text{loc}=\eta, \, \text{scale}=\lambda, \, a=\gamma,\, b=\delta$$

The constraints look identical to me between scipy and wikipedia, as well.

Comment: if `scale` and `loc` are mean and standard deviation, is $a$ and $b$ skewness and kurtosis? or have a less direct shaping effect on skewness and kurtosis?

Comment: `scale` and `loc` are not necessarily equal to mean and std.  See the [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson%27s_SU-distribution) for the relationship between the parameters and mean and std. Similary, the skewness and kurtosis will be complicated functions of _all_ the parameters (no reference on hand however)

Comment: is there a reference for the algorithm behind how python's `getattr()` extracts the best fitting parameters?

Comment: You can see details here: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_continuous.fit.html#scipy.stats.rv_continuous.fit and the code here: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.5.2/scipy/stats/_distn_infrastructure.py#L2198-L2336

Comment: what do I set `a` and `b` to (and any transformation therefore that might be needed) if I want a Johnson SU distribution that has a mean of 0.01, sdev of 0.15, skewness of 0.02, and kurtosis of 5?